# Facebook already shared content not sharing that content instant of share other content

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

My web site have facility to share 2 thing on Facebook

1. Share web site(with site logo and some thing about website) on Facebook and
2. Share question answer(with site logo and question answer) from the list of these on Facebook.

When i will share a question answer from my web site on Facebook than its work fine it would share that question answer.But if i will share again that already share question form Facebook that time it share the web site(with logo and some thing about website).

My code to share on FB:-

```
function shareOnFacebook(question, answer, id, url, appkey) {
   FB.init({
      appId: appkey,
   }); 
   var logourl = url + '/Resources/image/logo.png';
   if (id == 0) {
      LinkUrl =  url+'/home/home.aspx';
   }
   else {
      LinkUrl = url + '/patient/questiondetails.aspx?questionid=' + id;
   }
   FB.ui(
   {
      method: 'feed',
      name: unescape(question),
      description: (
        unescape(answer)
      ),
      link: LinkUrl,
      picture: logourl
   },
   function (response) {
      if (response && response.post_id) {
         alert('Post was published.');
      } else {
         alert('Post was not published.');
      }
   });
}
```

Anyone know why this is happening

Comment: How could one know without even looking at your code?

Comment: I've update the question please check

Comment: And how are you calling `shareOnFacebook` function?

Comment: On share icon click shareOnFacebook(questiontext,answertext,questionid, url,FBappkey)

Comment: You must be sending `0` as `id` in the function in second time. That's why the home page is shared.

Comment: its share fine form my web site but problem when i shared from Facebook again that is mention in question.

Comment: Sorry, but you are not clear with your problem!

Comment: When i will share a question that time pass question id(whatever) from question list page and when i will share the web site that time pass 0 as question id from site home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i found solution for my own question it is as followed

On questiondetails.aspx page load i need to dynamically update og:title and og:description meta tag as which question is selected.

First time when i share then it share by FB.ui method so it take title and description from javascript but when it share from Facebook that time it take title and description from meta tag and before this solution Facebook take meta tag from master page, that content web site name as title and description of web site as description.